# How can I improve the time complexity of this algorithm for finding the max stock price?

Tags: python, algorithm, time-complexity

I am currently passing the sample tests and 2 of the other 10 cases so 4 out of 12. However, I don't make it through all of the data. I am getting a Terminated due to timeout error which means that my solution isn't fast enough.

```
def stockmax(prices):
    total = 0 
    for index, price in enumerate(prices):
        if index < len(prices) - 1: 
            section = max(prices[index+1:])

            if prices[index] < section:
                total += section - prices[index]
    return total
```

I tried to do everything in only one loop. But how exactly can speed this type of question up.  I also tried to cut some lines of the code but it is equally as inefficient.

```
def stockmax(prices):
    total = 0 
    for index, price in enumerate(prices):
        if index < len(prices) - 1 and prices[index] < max(prices[index+1:]): 
              total += max(prices[index+1:]) - prices[index]
    return total
```

Though it passes the same amount of test cases. 
I also tried to use heapq but it passes the same test cases and fails due to time.

```
def stockmax(prices):
    total = 0 
    for index, price in enumerate(prices):
        if index < len(prices) - 1:
            section = heapq.nlargest(1,prices[index+1:])[0]
            if prices[index] < section: 
                total += section - prices[index]
    return total
```

---

https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/stockmax/topics/dynamic-programming-basics
for details on the problem.
https://hr-testcases-us-east-1.s3.amazonaws.com/330/input09.txt?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJ4WZFDFQTZRGO3QA&Expires=1538902058&Signature=3%2FnfZzPO8XKRNyGG0Yu9qJIptgk%3D&response-content-type=text%2Fplain
for a link of some test cases but will expire after a while.

Problem

Your algorithms have become so good at predicting the market that you now know what the share price of Wooden Orange Toothpicks Inc. (WOT) will be for the next number of days.

Each day, you can either buy one share of WOT, sell any number of shares of WOT that you own, or not make any transaction at all. What is the maximum profit you can obtain with an optimum trading strategy?

For example, if you know that prices for the next two days are `prices = [1,2]`, you should buy one share day one, and sell it day two for a profit of 1. If they are instead `prices = [2,1]`, no profit can be made so you don't buy or sell stock those days.

Function Description

Complete the stockmax function in the editor below. It must return an integer that represents the maximum profit achievable.

`stockmax` has the following parameter(s):

prices: an array of integers that represent predicted daily stock prices

Input Format

The first line contains the number of test cases `t`.

Each of the next `t` pairs of lines contain:

- The first line contains an integer `n`, the number of predicted prices for WOT.
- The next line contains n space-separated integers `prices [i]`, each a predicted stock price for day `i`.

Constraints

```
1 <= t  <= 10
1 <= n <= 50000
1 <= prices [i] <= 100000
```

Output Format

Output  lines, each containing the maximum profit which can be obtained for the corresponding test case.

Sample Input

```
3
3
5 3 2
3
1 2 100
4
1 3 1 2
```

Sample Output

```
0
197
3
```

Explanation

For the first case, you cannot obtain any profit because the share price never rises. 
For the second case, you can buy one share on the first two days and sell both of them on the third day. 
For the third case, you can buy one share on day 1, sell one on day 2, buy one share on day 3, and sell one share on day 4.

Comment: I have also tried using the heapq module  because I researched and read it is faster than max()  however it fails and passes the same amount of test cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clearly, for any price we can buy, we would want to sell it at the highest price. Fortunately, we are given that highest price. So, iterating backwards, we know the highest future price seen at any point we visit in our travel "back in time."

Python code:

```py
def stockmax(prices):
  n = len(prices)
  highest = prices[n - 1]
  m = [0] * n

  # Travel back in time,
  # deciding whether to buy or not
  for i in xrange(n - 2, -1, -1):

    # The most profit buying stock at this point
    # is what we may have made the next day
    # (which is stored in m[i + 1])
    # and what we could make if we bought today
    m[i] = m[i + 1] + max(
      # buy
      highest - prices[i],
      # don't buy
      0
    )

    # Update the highest "future price"
    highest = max(highest, prices[i])

  return m[0]
```

Comment: A problem with this solution, as well as for the OP, is that the time complexity will be O(n^2), due to the `max` operation. Even if there is only one apparent loop, each max operation, will require another look at all the elements in the list, effectively adding another walk through of all the elements. That will likely make also this solution break the time constraints on a solution.

Comment: @JohanL this solution has `O(n)` complexity. Why don't  you just try submitting it? :) (Hint: look more carefully at what `max` is comparing.)

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read it properly. I only saw the `max` calls. But they are not over the whole range of the input data, but only two elements, which obviously makes it O(n). My bad! Sorry! I am not the OP and cannot submit it. :-)

Comment: @JohanL no worries. Anyone can login there with a Google (or other) account I believe.

Comment: @גלעדברקן -  very elegant idea

Comment: @גלעדברקן  Your solution is very intuitive. Where did you learn to code? How can I gain this thought process? I am in a coding boot camp right now and really trying to learn.  Any online courses or books?

Comment: @JonathanHolloway I have to say that most of what I learned about dynamic programming and other interesting algorithmic approaches was actually by trying to solve problems presented on SO and reading other people's answers and related material I found online (over the course of a few years).

Answer (score 0):

If you can use Numpy, then something similar to the below should be rather quick (I believe it's the same idea as the answer from @גלעד ברקן).

```
import numpy as np

with open('.../input09.txt') as fd:
    numtests = int(fd.readline().strip())
    counter = 0
    numvals = 0
    vals = None
    steps = None
    for line in fd:
        if (counter % 2 == 0) :
            numvals = int(line.strip())
        else:
            vals = np.fromstring(line, dtype=int, sep=' ', count=numvals)
            assert len(vals) == numvals

            cum_max = np.maximum.accumulate(vals[::-1])
            np.roll(cum_max, -1)
            cum_max[len(cum_max) - 1] = 0
            delta = (cum_max - vals)
            print('#', counter + 1, 'sum:', np.sum(delta * (delta > 0)))

        counter += 1
```

it runs almost instantly on tests from the `input09.txt`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution written in ruby.
The solution obtained perfect score.

```rb
def solution(a)
  gain = 0
  i = a.count - 1
  min = false
  mi = false

  while i > 0
    s = a.delete_at(i)

    unless min
      mi = a.index(a.min)
      min = a[mi]
    end
    g = s - min
    gain = g if g > gain
    i -= 1
    min = false if i == mi
  end
  gain
end
```